# How to return the number of children for tree nodes in Sequelize?

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have a hierarchical tree data structure defined like this:

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
    var Category = sequelize.define('Category', {
            id: { type: DataTypes.STRING, primaryKey: true },
            parent: DataTypes.STRING,
            text: DataTypes.STRING
        }
    );
    Category.belongsTo(Category, { foreignKey: 'parent' });
    return Category;
};
```

I have a service returning the list of children for a given node like this:

```
exports.categoryChildren = function(req, res) {
    var id = req.params.id;
    db.Category.findAll({ where: { parent: id }}).success(function(categories){
        return res.jsonp(categories);
    }).error(function(err){
        return res.render('error', { error: err, status: 500 });
    });
};
```

Is there a way to make Sequelize to return the number of grandchildren for every child of the given node (i.e. the grandchildren of the given node)?

The SQL query I'd use for that looks like this:

```
SELECT *, (select count(*) from Categories chld where chld.parent = cat.id) 
FROM `Categories` cat 
WHERE cat.`parent`='my_node_id';
```

However, I can't find a way to force Sequelize to generate a query like that.

Comment: now there is a npm package to address this issue: [sequelize-hierarchy](https://github.com/overlookmotel/sequelize-hierarchy)

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using two nested queries as shown below.

Pros: I'm staying within the ORM paradigm.

Cons: the obvious performance hit.

```
exports.categoryChildren = function(req, res) {
    var id = req.params.id;

    db.Category.findAll({ where: { parent: id }}).success(function(categories) {
        var categoryIds = [];
        _.each(categories, function(element, index, list) {
            categoryIds[element.id] = element;
        });
        db.Category.findAll({attributes: [['Categories.parent', 'parent'], [Sequelize.fn('count', 'Categories.id'), 'cnt']], where: { parent: { in: _.keys(categoryIds) }}, group: ['Categories.parent']}).success(function(counts) {
            _.each(counts, function(element, index, list) {
                categoryIds[element.dataValues.parent].dataValues.cnt = element.dataValues.cnt;
            });
            return res.jsonp(categories);
        }).error(function(err){
            return res.render('error', {
                error: err,
                status: 500
            });
        });
    }).error(function(err){
        return res.render('error', {
            error: err,
            status: 500
        });
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue. So far the only thing I could figure out to do was using raw queries.

There are just some things ORMs can't do, I think this might be one of those things. You can just use `query()`

```
sequelize.query('select * from all_counts').success(function(counts) {...})
```

Comment: Raw SQL query is a good fallback strategy.  If the performance will be an issue I'll resolve to that.  The concern, however, is that I'll have to hardcode the table name basically exposing the DB schema to the code, and that's what I'd like to avoid by using ORM.

Comment: Yeah I use ORM to more make things easier in places it can. You will find that it's near impossible to find an ORM that won't eventually require to write some raw queries to boost performance

Answer (score 0):

Just did not use ORM to calculate that kind of stuff. It is performance disaster.

Use database queries (like SQL you specified) and define view for that SQL, and use model to work with that view.